# How to access elements from settings.xml in pom.xml with Maven?

Tags: maven, pom.xml, maven-profiles, maven-repository

According to https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#properties it should be possible to use `${settings.x}` to access the element `<settings><x>value</x></settings>` from the settings.xml file in the pom.xml file.

However, when I try something like

```
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <activation>
        <file>
          <exists>${settings.localRepository}/path/to/file</exists>
        </file>
      </activation>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
```

in my pom.xml it isn't replaced in the effective pom.xml. When I replace `${settings.localRepository}` with `${user.home}/.m2/repository` it works fine but that's not what I want. Is there anything I can do to fix that? (Tested with Apache Maven 3.6.0.)

**Background information:**
I have a dependency that isn't present in an online maven repository and I can't change that. It must be compiled by users and can be installed to the local repository. Instead of doing this manually, I'm trying to do this automatically in my pom.xml. For this I have to ignore the dependency if it's not present in the local repository. Hence the profile that checks if the file is present in the local repository. Without the profile, maven wouldn't even start the life cycle because the dependency can't be resolved. Of course the project won't compile the first time the pom.xml is executed. But all dependencies are automatically installed and the project will compile in a second pass. I know that this isn't a clean solution but I think it's better than telling users to compile and install dependency xy manually before this project can be compiled. I also include a build script that first runs `mvn clean initialize` to install the dependencies and then `mvn clean compile`.

Comment: Can you explain why do you like to do such things in your pom file?

Comment: Sounds like the need for a repository manager...or an external one which provides the needed one which is secured by appropriate credentials...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the source of the external dependency in an own project like:

```
+- main
   +- pom.xml ... <packaging>pom...<module>external...<module>internal
   |
   +- external
   |  +- ... Maven dirs as usual ...
   |  + pom.xml
   |
   +- internal
      +- ... Maven dirs as usual ...
      +- pom.xml ... <dependency>external
```

Such when building `main` the [*Maven Reactor*](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html) takes care of the projects' build order (build `external` first, then `internal` in this case) and you can forget about dealing with `settings.xml`, repositories, profiles or properties.

Comment: Thanks, I will accept this answer as it is a possible solution to my actual problem. However, I would still like to know why I can't access elements from settings.yml although it's documented.

Comment: @stonar96 It's not just a "possible" solution. It's THE canonical Maven solution. :) Everything else is more working against Maven rather than with it.